# PHP match for strings between two (starting, ending) delimters

Tags: php, regex

String;
`RandomValue1:|RandomSentence1.|RandomValue2:|RandomSentence2.|`

I'm trying to match `RandomSentence1.` and `RandomSentence2.`. I figured the "." in the sentence could be used to help the matching since every sentence ends with a period. So if I don't have the period in my match.  I'm OK with that. I've never been very good at RegEx but I'm always willing to try and learn.  Through the results on here I haven't been able to come up with anything that works.  I'd be coding this in PHP.  I believe either preg_match() or preg_split() would be the usage here.

I initially tried; `.*:\|.*\.\|`

But that just matches the entire string since it ends with `.|`.

Then I tried this; `.*:\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|`

But that only matched the `RandomSentence2.`

These are adaptions of what I've found online.

Comment: May be `.*:\|(.*\.)\|` to select what you need?

Comment: Use `preg_match_all('~[^|]*\|\K[^|]*~', $s, $m)`

Comment: You only need to make your regex lazy [`.*?:\|(.*?\.)\|`](https://regex101.com/r/fKqjy5/1)

Comment: Revo, that worked.  Just need to learn what you mean by lazy. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for a regex to capture all. Look for NOT `.` or `|` followed by `.` and `|`:

```
preg_match_all('/([^.|]+\.)\|/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

An alternate if you want to do something with the other entries would be to split and then find what you want.  Split on `|` then grep for array values ending in `.`:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/\.$/', explode('|', $string));
```

Comment: Revo's comment and your post both answer it.  I'll have to study the syntax of the regex and learn how it accomplished it.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know there is a dot at the end, you can just match all
with something simple `(?<=\|)[^|.]+(?=\.\|)`

https://regex101.com/r/ZsHcWq/1

```
 (?<= \| )
 [^|.]+ 
 (?= \.\| )
```